# Change default scope in CDI Beans

Tags: scope, cdi

is it possible to change the default scope of CDI Beans (dependent scope) to something else (like ApplicationScope)?
Thanks

Comment: Why would you need that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no simple API call or configuration property to do that, but you can always write a portable extension to add or replace scope annotations by observing the `ProcessAnnotatedType`event.